# C function, Network programming

Tags: c, string, network-programming

I have this C function.

```
void execMessage(int sockfd,void *structCHARMS, ClientData *client)
{
    ClientData *client_recv = (ClientData *) structCHARMS;

    client->local_addr=client_recv->local_addr;
    client->mode = client_recv->mode;

    char*msg;   
    CharmsMsg chmsg = {charms_msg_map[XTypes_CONFIG_PARAM].msg_code, client, 1184};
    msg = encode(&chmsg, "0.01");
    ssize_t n = 0;
    n = send(sockfd,msg,strlen(msg), 0);

}
```

It is called from main function of a classical TCP Server connected to TCP client. It creates a message ( with a particular function encode) and sent this to server.

The problem is : when insert this function in the same file of `main()`,it works correctly, but when  I insert this in another file I have "segmentation error fault" when program is running.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: In my crystal ball I see a static function in the other file. Its name is `encode()` or `strlen()` or `send()` Or is it a local typedef?

Comment: encode is a local typedef. strlen() and send() are C function. strlen() in string.h and send() in <sys/socket.h>. My problem is that when I insert this function in ServerTCP.c, file containing main() it works correctly.... but when i insert it in another file it doesn't work....particularly the send function doesn't work :(

Comment: You're using `encode` as a function, not a typedef.

Comment: Which line is the segmentation error happening on?

Comment: Run you program in a debugger and see why you're getting the segmentation fault. The debugger will stop the program when you hit it. Also, valgrind.

Comment: Please post your entire code if it's not too big; see if you can reduce it to a [short, self-contained, correct, compilable example](http://sscce.org/).  At the very least, post the definitions of the `encode()` function and the `struct ClientData` and `struct CharmsMsg` structures.

Comment: The segmentation error happens on last line because the msg isn't correctly setted. This happens only when I have this function in another file.

Comment: It's too big. The encode works correctly because I debug this code and encode return the correctly char* (it is a xml message)

Comment: @EngAndreaR: If `encode()` works, why is `msg` invalid? When this function is in "another file" as you put it, what does `encode()` do?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you need to figure out where exactly the program is segfaulting. Right now you make a local char* and pass the address of the pointer to the encode function. Do you have the code for that function available? It seems to me like you would want to return a pointer from the function and within it return heap your encoded c-string. After you send it you'll want to deallocate that memory so that you don't have a leak.

Comment: I've just debug the code. So encode() is a complex function and it returns a char*. I insert breakpoint in last line of encode() and I obtained this

Comment: Breakpoint 1, encode (chmsg=0x7fff5fbfc6f0, protocol_version=0x100008c90 "0.01") at protocol.c:46
46  return xmlbuffer;
(gdb) p xmlbuffer
$1 = 0x100807400 "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<MESSAGE>\n  <Header>\n    <Proto Ver=\"0.01\"/>\n    <Msg Type=\"CONFIG_PARAM\"/>\n    <Seq No=\"1184\"/>\n  </Header>\n  <Body>\n    <wait_for_config_param MaxRetransmissions=\"0\" FirstTimeo"... , so encode() works correctly

Comment: @EngAndreaR: What sort of pointer does `encode()` return?  Is it a pointer to a global variable?  A static variable?  A local stack-allocated variable?  A heap-allocated variable (e.g. with `malloc()` or `strdup()`)?

Comment: but when i arrive in send(), i have this 65  n = send(sockfd,msg,strlen(msg), 0);
(gdb) step

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000807400
0x00007fff8e7f56b0 in strlen ()

Comment: @EngAndreaR: we can't debug code we can't see. Try to reduce the scope of your code (e.g. replace this "big function" of yours with one that returns a hardcoded value) until you figure out where the problem is or you have a small enough piece of code that reproduces the problem (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: char *encode(CharmsMsg *chmsg, char *protocol_version)
{
 struct message msg;
 char *xmlbuffer;
 
 if((strcmp(protocol_version,"0.01")!=0) && (strcmp(protocol_version,"0.02")!=0))
 { 
  printf("versione del protocollo non supportata\n");
  exit(ERROR);
 }
 
 // riempie la struttura msg avvalendosi dei metadati
 create_message(&msg, chmsg, protocol_version);
 
 // genera il messaggio xml avvalendosi dei metadati e della libreria libxml2
 xmlbuffer = generate_xml(&msg);
 
 
 return xmlbuffer;
}    Encode function return xmlbuffer. And from my previous comment, the debug shows it works correctly

Comment: Is your program multi-threaded? If you're working from command line use gdb and printf statements to walk through until you find the line that is causing the segfault (or whatever the equivalent is if you're using an ide). It could very well be that you are trying to access the message somehow after you've released the memory or you are passing something by value instead of its address. If encode is working as you say it is we can't really help you debug it without looking at all of your code.

Comment: No it isn't multi-thread. The line that causes the segfault is:   n = send(sockfd,msg,strlen(msg), 0);   The message that gdb give me is: (gdb) step Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory. Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000807400 0x00007fff8e7f56b0 in strlen ()

Comment: @EngAndreaR: And what does the `generate_xml()` function look like?  You're really not being helpful to your own cause by withholding code.

Comment: I've solved the problem. I forget to include the header file containing encode function. I'm not an expert C programmer :(